# mousedown and mouseup events stop firing when I update the UI in a Dispatcher.Invoke call

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls

Okay, so I have an image element in my xaml inside a usercontrol

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="imagePiece" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Path=PieceGrid}" />
```

In the code behind I have in the constructor this:

```
AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(imagePiece_MouseDown), true);
AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(imagePiece_MouseUp), true);
```

I dynamically create several of these usercontrol's. The mousedown and mouseup work great and do exactly as I want. I can continually click the image and the event will fire every time.

However, I implemented a Timer object that fires every so often. That timer changes the image. In order to do that I have to do this:

```
private void releaseTheDaemon(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  int numberOfPieces = 0;
  List<GridPieceView> allPlacedPieces = new List<GridPieceView>();

  foreach (List<GridPieceView> list in piece)
  {
    foreach (GridPieceView p in list)
    {
      if (p.GridOwner != View.Owner.NotSelected)
      {
        allPlacedPieces.Add(p);
        numberOfPieces = numberOfPieces + 1;
      }
    }
  }

  int randIndex = randomNumber.Next(0, numberOfPieces);
  if (allPlacedPieces.Count > 0)
  {
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<GridPieceView>(daemonActions), allPlacedPieces[randIndex]);
  }
}

private void daemonActions(GridPieceView gridPiece)
{
  gridPiece.GridOwner = View.Owner.NotSelected;
  gridPiece.setPieceWhite();
}
```

The setPieceWhite() method is what updates the view. After that update occurs, the mousedown and mouseup are lost. They won't fire.

For kicks and giggles, I tried doing this to the method:

```
private void daemonActions(GridPieceView gridPiece)
{
  gridPiece.GridOwner = View.Owner.NotSelected;
  gridPiece.setPieceWhite();
  AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(gridPiece.imagePiece_MouseDown), true);
  AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(gridPiece.imagePiece_MouseUp), true);
}
```

But that really messed up the events, and anytime I clicked on one of the images, all the rest of the images that previously went through this method, are fired as well.

Anyways, does anyone know how I am suppose to handle this issue?

Comment: Well for the time being, every time the daemon strikes, I have just completely wiped all the user controls out and recreated them all. Not pretty but it is a workaround until I can figure out why the mouse events are getting unhooked during the dispatcher thread. Or until I can figure out how to re-hook them up.